# 1999 Honda Accord Coupe Stalls After Warm Startup and Shaky Idle TSB

Tags: honda, accord

The car will intermittently die at random times while doing errands or anything that requires frequent start/stop engine. Sometimes after starting it idles at about 500RPM, and dies. Shifting or running the air conditioner too soon can also help but isn't always the issue. Then I wait, turn the battery on, then start it minutes later and it runs fine.

I just installed a new idle speed control which seemed to help but not cure, a new battery, and a new alternator. There must be a TSB?

Comment: please clarify "TSB"

Answer (score 2):

I've been having this problem myself. From what I've read so far, the three main suspects are the main relay under the driver dash, the fuel pump relay, and the fuel pump, in that order.

Here are some links I visited, the symptoms described by other people with a faulty main relay are nearly identical:

http://www.askmehelpdesk.com/cars-trucks/1992-honda-accord-wont-start-7915.html
http://honda-tech.com/showthread.php?t=1360838

Answer (score 2):

I own a 1998 Honda Accord sedan that has gone through the same symptoms that you've experienced.  Often I would be driving down the street and, all of a sudden, the engine would just die without any warning at 60 km/h.  It also had extreme difficulty re-starting in hot weather (above 80 F) after it had just been running.
I had the main relay replaced, and the random-stalling-in-motion problem went away.  However, it still struggled to start in hot weather until I replaced the fuel pump.

This would be one of the TSB's for the 1998 Accord concerning the main relay; there is an identical TSB for the 1999:

[image: TSB for main relay]