# 97 Honda Civic dies in neutral

Tags: engine, honda, civic

I have a 97 Honda Civic that will occasionally die in neutral. This is what I have done so far:

- Replace both O2 sensors
- Replace MAP sensor
- Replace Air filter
- Added Lucas treatment to fuel tank

Even after the above changes, occasionally when coasting in neutral the rpm's will eventually drop to 0 and the engine will die. It starts back up just fine. My engine and fuel mileage have definitively improved with all the changes, especially after using Lucas.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the main relay, and the distributor cap and rotor is also a likely culprit.

[http://www.amazon.com/Beck-Arnley-203-0129-Main-Relay/dp/B001KSEKCK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KSEKCK)

[1999 Honda Accord Coupe Stalls After Warm Startup and Shaky Idle TSB](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/1999-honda-accord-coupe-stalls-after-warm-startup-and-shaky-idle-tsb/4641#4641)

Comment: I will research the main relay replacement. I do need to replace the distributor o-ring as it is leaking oil.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the oil leak then replace the distributor assembly. Oil covers the cam sensor eye inside the distributor causing the ecm to lose its position and stall out. Pull the distributor cap and see if any oil has gotten inside the housing.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is it's related to the fuel system. So I'd be testing the fuel pressure. If fuel pressure is fine, then check the injectors.